# Was custom pagination available in .Net Framework 4, If yes how we can implement?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

Was custom pagination available in .Net Framework 4, If yes how we can implement?

Currently I am implementing this by using GridView.VirtualItemCount however this is not avaible in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, it would seem that VirtualItemCount is not available in .net 4.0.

However, GridViews still supported paging in .net 4.0.

So, if I have a gv, and turn on paging like this:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"
            DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default"
                     OnClick="cmdDelete_Click" 
                     OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"   >
                   <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                   Delete                            
                   </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And code to load - (don't load with a data reader - they don't work - you need a "interable" data source.

So, code to load the grid can be this:

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE Description is not null 
             Order by HotelName"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rst As New DataTable
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rst
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And it outputs the grid - with a working pager:

[image]

So, no virtualItemCount seems to be available, but you can still turn on data paging with the gv in .net 4.0.